# did i install my google analytic code wrong?

Tags: google, html, analysis

I inserted this Google analytics code into my family tree web page and after a few days i still get that no activity has been reported

[can anyone take a look and see if there is any reason why this would not be working correctly?](http://www.barbrow.com/BarbrowTree/default.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like there's any analytics code on there, so that's most likely the problem. :-)

Copy and paste your code from the analytics site to your website and paste it down near the BOTTOM of the page before the ending `</body>` tag.

Also, I don't think you're going to see any reporting right away.  I think it takes 12-24 hours before you start seeing stuff.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it look correct now?

Comment: I can see code on the page now, yes.  So, if that's the code Google told you to cut and paste, you should be able to see some statistics within about 24 hours.  You'll want to place that code on every page you wish to track.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any GA code on that site.  You're going to want to place it right before the closing body tag on every single page you want to track.  In your case, every page that loads in those frames will need the GA code.

Comment: Does it look correct now?